# What can be said about the dual space of an infinite-dimensional real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

What can be said about the dual space of an infinite-dimensional real vector space?

Are both spaces isomorphic? Or shall we have something like the dual of the dual is isomorphic to the initial vector space (same as with the perpendicular subspace in a Hilbert space)?

Comment: The dual space of an infinite-dimensional vector space is always strictly larger than the original space, so no to both questions. This was discussed on MO but I can't find the thread.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu for the result.

Comment: The MathOverflow question Qiaochu was probably referring to is at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the abstract vector space case, where "dual space" is the algebraic dual (the vector space of *all* linear functionals), a vector space is isomorphic to its (algebraic) dual if and only if it is finite dimensional.

Bill Dubuque gives a nice argument in a sci.math post (see [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/8aeaiKMLP8o/2IqZlhlzdCIJ) or [MathForum](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7216370))

If $\mathbf{V}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbf{F}$ of dimension $d$, then the cardinality of $\mathbf{V}$ *as a set* is equal to $d|\mathbf{F}|=\max\{d,|\mathbf{F}|\}$, and $\mathbf{V}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{F}^{(d)}$ (functions from a set of cardinality $d$ to $\mathbf{F}$ with finite support), and the dual $\mathbf{V}^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{F}^d$ (*all* functions from a set of cardinality $d$ to $\mathbf{F}$), so $|\mathbf{V}^*| = |\mathbf{F}|^d$.

If the dimension of $\mathbf{V}^*$ is $d'$, we want to show that $d'\gt d$. Note that, as with $\mathbf{V}$, we have $|\mathbf{V}^*|=d'|\mathbf{F}| = \max\{d',|\mathbf{F}|\}$.

Now let $\{\mathbf{e}_n\}$ be a countable linearly independent subset of $\mathbf{V}$, and extend to a basis. For each $c\in \mathbf{F}$, $c\neq 0$, define $\mathbf{f}_c\colon \mathbf{V}\to\mathbf{F}$ by $\mathbf{f}_c(\mathbf{e}_n) = c^n$, and making $\mathbf{f}_c$ equal to $0$ on the rest of the basis. Thet set of all $\mathbf{f}_c$, $c\neq 0$, is linearly independent, so we can conclude that the dimension if $\mathbf{V}^*$ must be at least equal to $|\mathbf{F}|$ (in the finite case, we know the dimension is at least $d\gt |\mathbf{F}|$).

That means that 
$$|\mathbf{V}^*| = d'|\mathbf{F}| = \max\{d',|\mathbf{F}|\} = d'.$$

But we also know that $|\mathbf{V}^*| = |\mathbf{F}|^d$. Since $d< |\mathbf{F}|^{d}$ (since $|\mathbf{F}|\geq 2$), then $d' = |\mathbf{F}|^d\gt d$, proving that the dimension of $\mathbf{V}^*$ is strictly larger (in the sense of cardinality) than that of $\mathbf{V}$.

The isomorphism in the finite dimensional case is standard.

So for the algebraic dual, there is never an isomorphism in the infinite dimensional case.

In the Hilbert space case (or in a Banach space, or more generally a topological vector space), one usually restricts to the *continuous* (or bounded) functionals, so that $\mathbf{V}^*$ denotes the bounded functionals rather than the regular functions. In that case, some spaces are topological-vector-space isomorphic to their double duals, and some not, as AD shows in his answer. The ones that are isomorphic are important enough to get their own name (reflexive). Hilbert spaces are *always* reflexive, and there are other classes of topological vector spaces that are always reflexive (see Wikipedia's page on reflexive spaces).

Comment: For further elaboration see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals/58598#58598)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have the following:  Suppose that $E $ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Then, there exists a dual space $E^*$ such that the natural injection $E^* \rightarrow L (E)$ is not surjective, where $L (E) $ is the set of linear mappings $\varphi : E \rightarrow \Gamma $ ($\Gamma$ is a field).  Is this true?

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh: **A** field, or the field of scalars? If it’s just a field, then you don’t need to go to infinite dimension: the natural embedding of $\mathbb{R}^*$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is not surjective. If you mean the field of scalars, then *by definition* you ahve that $E^*$ *is* the set of linear mappings from $E$ to the field, so no.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  In my context all vector spaces are defined over a fixed, but arbitrarily chosen field $ \Gamma $ of characteristic $ 0 $

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh: Then, as I already told you, the answer is “no”. By *definition* the dual space **is** $L(E)$, so the natural injection is called the identity map. It’s surjective. The dimension of $E$ is utterly irrelevant. In the infinite dimensional case, the canonical map $E\to L(E^*)$ is the one that is not surjective.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin   Why in the infinite dimensional case, the canonical map $E → L (E^*)$ is not surjective?
 I thought that when $ E $ is infinite dimensional, then the mapping $ E^* \rightarrow L (E) $ is not surjective for some dual space $ E^* $.

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh: I don’t know why you thought that. It’s just not true. As to why the double dual is no longer isomorphic, because the dimensions don’t match any more. *This very posts proves that.* Did you read it? Seems to me that you don’t actually know what the dual space is, which makes this a rather silly conversation...

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh: Also, you keep using the wrong article. “A” means one of many. There is **one** dual space, so you should talk about **the** dual space $E^*$, not **a** dual space. There is **one** field of scalars, so you should talk about **the** field of scalars, not **a** field of scalars. Using incorrect and imprecise language just gets in the way of accurate communication.

Answer (score 15):

No, this is not the case in general. For example, take the real vector space of finite sequences $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers. Then every sequence $\{b_n\}$ of real numbers (finite or infinite) defines a linear function on this space via $\sum_n{a_nb_n}$, and the spaces of finite sequences and infinite sequences are not isomorphic.

Comment: Vielen danke joriki

Comment: @El Moro: Actually, my initial answer contained an error since the *cardinality* of the spaces of finite and infinite sequences of reals is the same (namely that of the reals), just not the dimension -- I've deleted that part and will replace it with a more careful argument.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what you mean by the question. The *algebraic dual* of an infinite dimensional space is [strictly larger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#The_infinite-dimensional_case). For the *topological dual* of a topological vector space  $X$ we may very well have  $X^{**}=X$.

**Example 1.**
Sometimes we do have $X^{**}=X$ (read isometric to not equal to) for an infinite dimensional topological vector space, such space is said to be [reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space). The basic example is $X=L^p$ where $1<p<\infty$, in this case we have $(L^p)^*=L^q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$. ([Here is a link to a wikipedia article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces) also look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Double_dual) ).

**Example 2.**
Sometimes we have $X^{**}\ne X$ for an infinite dimensional topological vector space. The basic example is $L^1$, where we have $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$ while $(L^\infty)^*$ is a larger space of measures (containing $L^1$). (The same link as above applies).