# Example of an infinite dimensional vector space that is not isomorphic to its dual

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why are vector spaces not isomorphic to their duals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals)
>   [Dual space question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/dual-space-question)

Can someone give an (as easy as possible) example (together with a proof) of an infinite dimensional vector space that is not isomorphic to its dual ?

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/dual-space-question.

Answer (score 4):

We can consider $l^1$, the vector space of the sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|x_n|<\infty$. The dual can be identified with $l^{\infty}$, the vector space of all bounded sequences. But these two spaces cannot be isomorphic, since the first is separable whereas the second is not.