# Dual of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Consider the free $k$-algebra $k[x_i]_{i \in I}$ indexed by $I$. Then is
$Hom_{k-Mod}(k[x_i]_{i \in I},k) \cong k[x_i]_{i \in I}$?

Comment: This already fails for a one element $I$; the dimension of $k[x]$ as a vector space over $k$ is countable, the dual has uncountable dimension.

Comment: @egreg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I'll do it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

This already fails for $I$ a singleton: the dimension of $k[x]$ as a vector space over $k$ is countable, while the dual
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{k\text{-Mod}}(k[x],k)
$$
has uncountable dimension.

See [*Slick proof? A vector space has the same dimension as its dual if and only if it is finite dimensional*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i%20for%20a%20simple%20proof.) on MathOverflow.

So the result above is general for any set of indeterminates.

Comment: Better, stay on MSE where you can [find a proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/35863/242) wtihout the defects of the linked MO proof.