# Isomorphic homology and cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW-complex of finite dimension and $F$ be a field.
Do we have that $H^q(X;F)=H_q(X;F)$ for each $q\leq n$?
I know that with filed coefficients the universal coefficient theorem simplifies so that 
$H^q(X;F)=Hom_F(H_q(X;F),F)$ but do we have an isomorphism between $H^q(X;F)$ and $H_q(X;F)$?
If no, then under what conditions on $F$ or $X$ this would be true? thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, if $X$ has finitely many cells in each dimension (the term "finite dimension" is a bit ambiguous).

Comment: Ok thanks Justin!!

Answer (score 0):

See [Dual space question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/dual-space-question) for why there is no isomorphism of $H_i$ and $H^i$ in general. To make a simple example, take $X$ which is zero-dimensional of cardinality $d$. Then $H_0(X; F)\cong F^d$ 
while $H^0(X; F)\cong Hom(F^d, F)$. However, $F^d$ is not in general isomorphic to   $Hom(F^d, F)$.