# If V is infinite dimensional, then V and V* are not isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm following the proof in
http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~parks/sample338.pdf .

**Theorem 5** If V is infinite dimensional, then V and $V^∗$ are not isomorphic.

**Proof** $B$ basis of $V$, $\kappa=|B|$. **Case I** $2^{\aleph_0}\leq \kappa$. For each subset $S\subset B$ we can define a distinct element
$$
\sum_{b\in S}b^*.
$$
Thus we see that the cardinality of $V^∗$ is at least $2^\kappa$ which is strictly greater than $\kappa = \kappa\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$, the cardinality of V.
**Case II** not relevant for the question.

> What is the relation between $|B|$ and $|V|$?

I understand that $|B|=\kappa\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ is given, and that $|V^*|\geq 2^\kappa$. Additionally I have the identity for infinite $V$
$$
|V|=\textrm{max}(|\mathbb{F}|,|B|),
$$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field under the vector space. Am I correct if I say that the author makes the assumption $|\mathbb{F}|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$?

And another question (to understand where $\kappa = \kappa\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$ comes from): Is $|V|=\textrm{max}(|\mathbb{F}|,|B|)$ equivalent to $|V|=|\mathbb{F}|\cdot|B|)$?

Comment: At the beginning of the paper, the author speaks of real vector spaces. So $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ which is of cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twice yes: the first line of the linked note says we are considering vector spaces
over the real numbers. So $|\mathbb{F}| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$

And for all infinite cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$ $$\kappa \cdot \lambda = \kappa + \lambda = \max(\kappa, \lambda)$$

(at least if we assume the axiom of choice (AC), which we do, because we assume a vector space always has a basis)

So for all vector spaces over an infinite field $|V| = |\mathbb{F}| \cdot |B|$ (because we use *finite* linear combinations from $B$ to get all of $V$), so over the reals : $|V| = \mathfrak{c} \cdot |B|$ and so in case (i), when $|B| \ge 2^{\aleph_0}$: $|V| = |B|$, while the argument shows the first inequality in $$|V^\ast| \ge 2^{|B|} > |B| = |V|$$ the last inequality by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: If you know a book with the general prove would be nice. I found only *Roman, Advanced Linear Algebra, 2008*. Perhaps I try again with his proof.

Comment: @LiPo the link you gave **has** the general proof. All basis-cardinalities have been done. In what sense do you need a more general proof? What is missing?

Comment: I mean general in respect to the cardinality of the field. $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not the the maximal cardinality for a field, is it?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35863/4280) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58598/4280) are other more extensive proofs on this site, for any field size. And by the (upward) Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, for every infinte cardinal $\kappa$ there is a field of that size.