# Proving entire sequence space and the subspace of sequences with finitely many non-zero entries are not isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the vector space of all real-valued sequences (over the field of real numbers), i.e., $$\mathbb{R}^{\infty}:= \{f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}.$$
On the other hand, denote by $\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the subspace consisting of all real-valued sequences with only finitely many components non-zero, i.e., $$\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}:= \left\{f\in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}\,\vert\, f(n)\ne 0 \text{ for finitely many $n$}\right\}.$$
(Here, addition and scalar multiplication for these vector spaces is defined in the usual way.) Obviously both spaces are uncountable and $\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ are not isomorphic as vector spaces. I am not sure if going down a route of computing cardinalities is the way to go, or another way.

Comment: The space $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is the dual of $\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}$: the latter has a basis consisting of functions $\mathbf{f}_i$ with $\mathbf{f}_i(j) = \delta_{ij}$. For infinite dimensional spaces, [the dual is never isomorphic to the space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/dual-space-question/35863#35863)

Comment: Cardinality by itself won't do it; $|\mathbb{R}^{\infty}| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{N}|} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$; and $2^{\aleph_0}\leq |\mathbb{R}|\leq|\mathbb{R}_0^{\infty}|\leq |\mathbb{R}^{\infty}|= 2^{\aleph_0}$. So they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb R_0^{\infty}$ has a countable (Hamel) basis but $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ doesn't. If $\mathbb R^{\infty}$  has a countable basis then this space would be a countable union of finite dimensional spaces. By introducing the topology defined by the metric $d(x,y)=\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} \frac {|x_n-y_n|} {1+|x_n-y_n|}$ and applying Baire Category Theorem we get a contradiction since no proper subspace of $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ has an interior point.