# adding details to the proof that natural isomorphism between finite dimensional V and $V^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that V is finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Let $<-,->$ denote an inner on V.

Let $D : V \rightarrow V^{*}$ defined as
$$v \mapsto D(v)= \ <v,-> \ : V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$$

It is clear that D is linear. Assume that $D(v) = 0 \implies <v,->$ is the zero map.

In particular $<v,v> = 0 \implies \|v\| = 0 \implies v = 0$

I am having troubles proving that D is surjective.

Comment: For $v\neq 0$, $\langle v,v\rangle\neq 0$, so $\langle v,\alpha v\rangle$ takes all possible values as $\alpha$ ranges over your field.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: If someone adds the details I will accept the answer.

Comment: Though I guess what I did was show $D(v)$ is surjective for $v\neq 0$, rather than showing that we get all functionals. That we get all functionals depends on showing that $V^*$ has the same dimension as $V$; take an orthonormal basis for $V$, and show that the image in $V^*$ is linearly independent to conclude $D$ is onto. Note the result is false if $V$ is not finite dimensional, so you *need* to use finite dimensionality somewhere.

Comment: P.S. User `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a finite dimensional inner product space $V$, we know that $V^*$ has dimension $\dim(V)\dim(K) =\dim(V)$. To show that $D$ is onto, it suffices to exhibit a linearly independent subset of $\mathrm{Im}(D)$ with $\dim(V)$ elements.

To that end, let $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$. Then note that $D(\mathbf{v}_i)(\mathbf{v}_j) = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker’s delta). If $\alpha_1D(\mathbf{v}_1)+\cdots+\alpha_nD(\mathbf{v}_n) = \mathbf{0}$, then evaluating at $\mathbf{v}_i$ we conclude that $\alpha_i=0$. Thus, these images are linearly independent, and hence form a basis for $V^*$. This shows $D$ is surjective.

We need to use finite dimensionality, since the algebraic dual of an infinite dimensional vector space is *not* isomorphic to the space (canonically or otherwise). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/what-can-be-said-about-the-dual-space-of-an-infinite-dimensional-real-vector-spa) for a proof. The finite dimensionality occurs twice in the above proof: the existence of an orthonormal basis, and the dimension of $V^*$.

Comment: I proved it with your hints. I will accept your answer thank you.

Comment: My proof is more direct. It would help other people as well. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I posted a proof. Let me add more details to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L \in V^{*}$. Choose orthonormal basis {e_1,\ldots,e_n} of V.

$$L(v) = L(x_1e_1 + \ldots + x_ne_n) = x_1L(e_1) + \ldots x_nL(e_n)$$

Let $v^{\prime} = e_1 L(e_1) + \ldots e_n L(e_n)$. It follows that

$$D(v^{\prime})(v) =  D(e_1 L(e_1) + \ldots e_n L(e_n))(v) = \langle e_1 L(e_1) + \ldots e_n L(e_n), x_1e_1 + \ldots x_ne_n> = x_1L(e_1) + \ldots x_nL(e_n) \rangle  = T(v)$$