# Is my proof for any finite-dimensional vector space being isomorphic to its double dual correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, dual-spaces

Learning about dual vector spaces I began thinking about how the product of a row vector and a column vector acts like a dot product and that furthermore, the row vector is almost acting like a functional that takes in the column vector and outputs a real number. This made me think of the following way to prove that all vector spaces are isomorphic to their double dual:

First, recall that the set of all column vectors with $n$ entries forms a $n$-dimensional vector space. Furthermore, every vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to the vector space of column vectors with $n$ entries, $\mathscr C_n$. This can be shown through a simple change in basis. Therefore to show that any finite-dimensional vector space $V \cong V^{**}$, it suffices to show that $\mathscr C_n \cong \mathscr C_n^{**}$.

Consider the map $\phi : \mathscr C_n \rightarrow \mathscr C_n^*$ defined such that
$$\forall \mathbf v,\mathbf x \in \mathscr C_n : \phi(\mathbf v)(\mathbf x) = \mathbf v^T\mathbf x$$
If we can show that this map is (1) one-to-one, (2) onto, and (3) linear, then it follows that the image of any basis in $\mathscr C_n$ under $\phi$ is a basis of $\mathscr C^*$ and so $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Denote the vector space of all row vectors with n entries as $\mathscr R_n$. Then

$$\forall \mathbf f \in \mathscr R_n : \exists! \mathbf v \in \mathscr C_n : \mathbf f = \mathbf v^T \implies \forall  \omega \in \mathscr C_n^* : \exists! \mathbf v \in \mathscr C_n : \phi(\mathbf v) = \omega$$
So $\phi$ is (1) one-to-one and (2) onto.

Let $\mathbb F$ denote the underlying field for $\mathscr C_n, \mathscr R_n,$ and consequently $\mathscr C^*$. Now, note that $\forall \mathbf v,\mathbf w,\mathbf x \in \mathscr C_n, c \in \mathbb F:$

$$\phi(c\mathbf v)(\mathbf x) = (c\mathbf v)^T\mathbf x = c(\mathbf v^T\mathbf x) = c\phi(\mathbf v)(\mathbf x)\\\phi(\mathbf v+\mathbf w)(\mathbf x)=(\mathbf v+\mathbf w)^T\mathbf x=(\mathbf v^T+\mathbf w^T)\mathbf x=\mathbf v^T\mathbf x+\mathbf w^T\mathbf x=\phi(\mathbf v)(\mathbf x)+\phi(\mathbf w)(\mathbf x)$$
And so $\phi$ is (3) linear. Therefore $\phi$ is an isomorphism and so $\mathscr C_n \cong \mathscr C_n^* \implies \mathscr C_n^* \cong \mathscr C_n^{**}$, which implies that any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{**}$.

I know of the much simpler canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$, I just want to test my knowledge and see if this proof is also valid. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that this assumes finite dimension. The proof of being onto fails in infinite dimension.

Comment: @eyeballfrog And indeed the *result* [fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35779/what-can-be-said-about-the-dual-space-of-an-infinite-dimensional-real-vector-spa) for infinite dimension.

Comment: Your proof is fine (as you have qualified it by requiring the dimension to be finite).My inclination would have been to define $\phi(\mathbf{e}_i)$ for the standard basic vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ and extend that  by linearity, but your approach is just as good.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the isomorphism I describe is not "natural" because relating any vector space $V$ to $\mathscr C_n$ requires having knowledge of a basis in V?

Comment: @JohThe isomorphism in your proof is the canonical isomorphism.