# Definition of a degenrate bilinear form for infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

I'm a bit confused about what it means for a bilinear form to be degenerate in the context of infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form),

> [A] degenerate bilinear form $f(x, y)$ on a vector space $V$ is a bilinear form such that the map from $V$ to $V^∗$ (the dual space of $V$) given by $v \mapsto (x \mapsto f(x, v))$ is not an isomorphism. An equivalent definition when V is finite-dimensional is that it has a non-trivial kernel: there exist some non-zero $x$ in $V$ such that
> $$
> f(x, y) = 0 \;\text{ for all }\; y \in V
> $$

But since [an infinite-dimensional vector space is never isomorphic to its dual](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35863/1130444), then a bilinear form on an infinite dimensional vector space is always degenerate.

That doesn't seem right, so what is going on here?
I don't think it's talking about the continuous dual space, since $V$ is introduced as any vector space, i.e. no topology is given.

Of course I'm aware you can define "degenerate" to mean whatever you want,
so my question is specifically about *which* definition is commonly used
for a bilinear form to be "degenerate",
specifically when *not* only talking about finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Is there even such a thing, or is "degenerate" a notion that only really applies to
bilinear forms on finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Right, in the algebraic setting, to get a non-trivial definition it should say 'such that the map from $V$ to $V^*$ is not injective'. The Wikipedia article gives you an example where this can happen (so this isn't a vacuous definition). In the normed setting, one indeed considers the continuous dual, and there one introduces the notions of *weakly non-degenerate* (i.e the induced map is injective) and and *strongly non-degenerate* (i.e the induced map is an isomorphism), and of course one requires the maps in question to be continuous. (authors may choose to emphasize/omit the weak/strong).

Comment: And in the normed setting, there of course exist strongly non-degenerate bilinear maps (the prototype, by Riesz's theorem, being inner products on a Hilbert space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this depends on authors, but usually (especially when working over rings and not just fields), one says that a bilinear form is *nondegenerate* if it induces an *injection* from $V$ to its dual, and that it is *regular* when it induces an isomorphism.

For finite-dimensional vector spaces this is the same thing of course, but usually there is a difference, and in particular for infinite-dimensional vector spaces the notion of a regular bilinear form becomes void, as you noticed yourself, but you can still ask whether a form is nondegenerate.

Comment: Since there is a difference between the algebraic and the topological dual of a vector space, wouldn't regular bilinear forms be possible if they were referring to an isomorphism between V and its topological dual? (as some authors like Marsden actually talk about regular bilinear forms on infinite dimensional vector spaces, which however have to be reflexive)