# Dual of the annihilator isomorphic to quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

There are many resources online detailing the isomorphism between the annihilator $U^0:=\{f\in V':f(U)=0\}$ and the dual of the quotient space, $(V/U)':=Hom(V/U,\mathbb{R})$.

However, my lecture notes state without proof that we also have $V/U\cong (U^0)'$ - an isomorphism between the quotient space itself and the dual of the annihilator.

Could anyone please provide this isomorphism?

Comment: For finite dimensional vector spaces, it follows by taking duals and remembering that there is a canonical isomorphism between a finite dimensional vector space and its double dual. For infinite dimensional vector spaces it is false, as witnessed by taking $U$ to be the trivial subspace, and remembering that thar [the algebraic dual of an infinite dimensional vector space always has strictly larger dimension than the space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35863/742).

Comment: $(v+U)(f)=f(v)$.

Comment: Just use bidual iso ?